# LSB init service dependency

Tags: linux, unix, redhat, init, lsb

I have added the two services A and B. B is dependent on A means if i will start B then A should be start automatically if it is not running already. But A is not coming up automatically when i am starting B.

Can you please tell where am i wrong ?. I have mentioned the Init scripts for both the services below.

B Init script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Author: Jsingh <jsingh@sandvine.com>

# chkconfig: 2345 95 05

# processname:  B
# config: /usr/local/etc/rc.conf
# pidfile: /var/run/B.pid


### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: B
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network A
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network A
# Should-Start:
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start and stop System daemon
# Description:
### END INIT INFO
```

A Init Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Author:       Jsingh <jsingh@sandvine.com>

# chkconfig:    2345 90 10

# processname:  A
# config: /usr/local/etc/rc.conf
# pidfile: /var/run/A.pid


### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: A
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network
# Should-Start:
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start and stop System daemon
# Description: 
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: I dont want to use "upstart and systemd". I want to implement this logic in lsb init scripts.